# Ruby gem or snippet to use different ActiveRecord db connection depending on model attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, sharding

Can you suggest a ruby gem or show a snippet with exsmple how to make AtiveRecord::Base successor to choose a db connection depending on a model record id?

Comment: What database you are running? If you use postgres then you can use Schema instead of complete new database.

Comment: I use postgres and I need these dbs to be placed on different servers, so they appear could not be schemas, right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Please let me know if the following solution can work if not then I will delete it from here.

I wouldn't use Gem for this.

Here a mud map how I would tackle this project. ( for small to medium projects only )

[image]

- Ruby Class: manages all the connections.
- Query handler: dictates what connection do we need based on the
  condition.
- Connector is a simple class that grabs stuff from
  Rails and trigger the query handlers.

Query handler is the optional bit. You can connect your Rails directly to the Ruby Class. ( I don't like this as they will be coupled a bit too much )

Have your database.yaml file (just to keep Rails happy) Your application will be using the Ruby Class connector and query handler to grab stuff from different databases, No Rails needed there.

Hope this help!

PS: Again if you think this is not good solution let me know and I see what I can do. Cheers mate.

Comment: Hi, Mr H. Thank you for your response. I'm looking for references to complete stable solution, because I don't like the idea of developing such important part of project.

Comment: hmmm, fair enough. I leave the answer there incase it can help someone else. I will see if I can get a chance to make you a gem that does what you need, I think a middleware would do a better job.

Comment: Not sure if you found a solution. Have you seen this Gem. It might be a start: https://github.com/karledurante/secondbase